# Make the ball to slowly stop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As title says, I want my ball object to slowly stop when I've added force to it. I've already used `angularDrag = 1f`. But my ball seems continue rolling and never stop. (Just imagine soccer game, the ball slowly would stop on the grass.)

Here's my code:

```cs
public void pushBall(Vector3 forcePos)
{
    rb.AddForce(forcePos * strength);
    rb.angularDrag = 1f;
}
```

Comment: I've already used Physic Material and set Dynamic Friction to 1.0f. But the ball continues rolling. Or it takes lots lots of time to stop

Comment: Are you calling it in a update? how do you trigger it.

Comment: increase it and also increase the friction of the surface

Comment: The ball still moves and rotates, but in very slow speed, player can see it. :((

Comment: @MX D . What do you mean? can you give me an example code please

Comment: So the sprite still rotates? You just need to stop the sprite animation when the velocity of the object reaches zero.

Comment: The velocity can't reach zero too, it just come to very near to 0 :((((